# Call a controller when a menu is selected in single page application - MVC & angularJs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I have created a simple Single page application with angular js. I have a index page in which the route is defined and the ng-view is called.

Index.cshtml:

```
 @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

@{
    Layout = null;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>SPA</title>

    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="Index as ind">
        <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openDashboard()"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openAbout()"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" data-ng-click="openContact()"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div id="main">

            <!-- angular templating -->
            <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
    <%--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="../Controllers/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.constant('routes', [
    {
        url: '/',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.aspx',
            menuItem: 'MainPage'
        }
    },
    {
        url: '/about',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'about.aspx',
            menuItem: 'aboutPage'
        }
    },
    {
        url: '/contact',
        config: {
            templateUrl: 'contact.aspx',
            menuItem: 'contactPage'
        }
    }
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', '$controllerProvider', function ($routeProvider, routes, $controllerProvider) {

    //$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();

    app._controller = app.controller;

    // Provider-based controller.
    app.controller = function (name, constructor) {
        $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
        return (this);
    };

    routes.forEach(function (route) {
        $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
    });
}]);

var controllerId = 'Index';

app.controller(controllerId, function ($scope, $location) {
    var ind = this;

    $scope.openDashboard = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    }

    $scope.openOpportunity = function () {
        $location.path('/opportunity');
    }

    $scope.openContact = function () {
        $location.path('/contact');
    }
})
```

I have created three separate cshtml pages for each menu and separate .js file (in which controller is defined for each page).

When the page load, it calls dashboard page by default and it throws error as

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/ng/areq?p0=dashboardController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Here, dashboardController is the name of the controller defined in Dashboard page.

Dashboard.cshtml:

```
    <script src="../Controllers/dashboard.js"></script>

        <div data-ng-controller="dashboardController">
            {{message}}
        </div>
```

and the associated controller file is as follows (dashboard.js):

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var controllerId = 'dashboardController';

    app.controller(controllerId, function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello!!";
    });
})();
```

The other pages also have the same code and that too provide the above mentioned error when a menu is selected.

When I tried to call 'dashboard.js' file in index.cshtml itself, it display the page correctly.

But I don't want to call all the js file at the starting, since in future i will be using a large amount of data to display in each page and hence it might slow down the application.

Please let me know, how I should proceed to get the output by calling the controllers when that particular page is called.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

All of your application resources (controllers, etc.) need to be referenced in the main html page (in your case 'Index.cshtml'), not in the views.

Comment: If I call controllers from my index.cshtml file it works. But I don't want to call all the js file at the starting, since in future i will be using a large amount of data to display in each page and hence it might slow down the application.

Answer (score 0):

You just declare `<script src="../Controllers/dashboard.js"></script>` this script in bottom of `<script src="../Controllers/app.js"></script>` this script in **Index.cshtml**. I suggest you to go this method.

Comment: But if i do this now , in future i will be using a large amount of data to display in each page and hence it might slow down the application.

Comment: In future you must learn gulp or gruntt tool for minify your source code . For example you have 10 controllers and 10 services they are all different pages you have to minify 20 page to one page that is a best practice. and refer the below link https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js